# XPath targeting specific child and grandchild (child of child)

Tags: xpath

I am trying to target all the p tags, where there is no strong tag as a child or grandchild(child of the child) of the p tag.

here is the sample

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</a>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</a></strong>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <a><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</strong></a>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</a>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. <a><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</strong></a>
</p>
```

In the above code, the 2nd, 3rd, and last one are the ones that I don't want but I want the rest of them. I have gotten as far as this XPath:

`//p[not(child::strong)]` which removes the 2nd paragraph, but when i add the a>strong like  `//p[not(child::strong) or not(child::a > strong)]` the second part is being ignored. Can anyone point out where am I going wrong and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried like this `//p[not(.//strong) and not(.//a[strong])]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `//p[not(strong) and not(*/strong)]`.